# Why the output is different of the same equation?

Tags: c++

Please explain me why the output is different here of the same equation? Confused. 
 Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 9+2/4*3-2*4+1*3 * 9+2/4*3-2*4+1*3 + 6+3*3/5;
    int y = 9+ 0 *3-2*4+1*3 * 9+ 0 *3-2*4+1*3 + 6+3*0;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Output : 30
    printf("%d", y);    // Output : 29 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `3*3/5` is not the same as `3*0`

Comment: use seperate variables for the individual terms, then you will see that the equations are not the same

Comment: Oh. Newbie downvoting is ongoing. +1 from my end for the subtle difference of the first and the second term.

Comment: @ArminMontgny i can only speak for myself, but I see no newbie downvoting, i dont know what that should mean. I dont downvote newbies. However, I think OP could have investiged the equations to see if they really are the same

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be deduced by checking [Order of Evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)  and especially by reading about [Operator Precedence and Associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

You are rigth that for integer values the result of the division 3/5 = equal to 0. But for the wohle expression we have to look add the whole term 3*3/5. The precedence is higher than the + operation before. But within your term 3*3/5 the associativity is left to right. So, the term will be evaluated to 3*3 = 9 and then 9/5 which results in 1.

This is different in the first term 2/4*3. If we read from left to right then first 2/4 is evaluated to 0 and then multiplied by 3. The overall result is in this case 0.

Therefore the evaluated expressions differ by 1

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to take into consideration:
1-In your code the equations are not equivalent
2-the int datatype removes your decimal (ie: if x = 10.9 and you tried displaying x then it will print 10 because only the integer part is being stored)
3-Order of operations(Multiplication ,addition,etc...)

Comment: The line "if x = 10.9 and you tried displaying x then it will print 10" is slightly misleading. The issue isn't that only the integer part will be displayed, but rather that only the integer part is _stored_.

Comment: With all-out integer arithmetics, there never were any decimals to begin with.